# Why does a moving charge create electricity

Tags: electromagnetism

Now i have been studying a chapter called current electricity and i found out that moving chages can create electricity why is this possible? Is it the holes and the electrons combining together and creeating heat and light and us pecieving it as electricity?
I haven't put much thought into it but i am also very impatient about knowing what it really is.

Comment: Define electricity.  If you mean current, then moving charges do NOT create electric current they define electric current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term “electricity” doesn’t necessarily refer to any one specific thing, but rather to a whole class of phenomena related to charge, current, voltage, etc. However, it isn’t unreasonable to focus on current and say that electricity is current. So in the remainder of this answer I will talk about current.

More specifically, when a charge density, $\rho$, moves with a velocity, $\mathbf v$, there is a quantity, $\mathbf J = \rho \mathbf v$. It turns out that this quantity is very useful, so we give it a name: current density. Once you integrate the current density over the cross section of a wire you get current. So, roughly speaking moving charges don’t “create” current, they are current. It is just a matter of definition, but it is a very useful definition for studying electric circuits.

Comment: If the charges are current then why does current flow in the opposite diection of the charge?

Comment: Don’t forget that charge has a sign. If $\rho>0$ then clearly $\mathbf J$ is in the same direction as $\mathbf v$. If $\rho<0$ then clearly $\mathbf J$ is in the opposite direction as $\mathbf v$

Comment: But how can charge density become negative?

Comment: @Alexallee when v is negative

Comment: Okay but i feel like both of you are going for diffrent conclusions I'm bit confused.

Comment: @Alexallee well not really, but he is just explaining about charge currents

Comment: @Alexallee Charge density is negative for negatively charged particles. So if you have electrons in a volume, you get a negative charge density, if you have protons in a volume you have positive charge density.  QuIcKmAtHs is not correct to say that negative charge density is because of negative v, in this context they are independent quantities.

Comment: @Alex allee as Hugo V said you have a negative charge density when you have a surplus of negative charges (electrons) in a region.  You have a positive charge density when you have a surplus of positive charges (protons) in a region.

Answer (score 1):

Simply said, electricity is the phenomenon of the motion of matter that has electric charge, that is, a charged particle or any charged object.  A lightning, which is a daily example of electricity, is simply a flow of electrons, usually from a region of lower to higher potential.

Hence, if 2 regions have a potential difference, electrons will flow from the lower to higher one.  In your case the hole is a positive charge, and electron a negative charge.  The electron will be attracted to the hole.  A common analogy is the waterfall analogy.  The top of the waterfall is analogous to a negatively charged region, while the bottom to a positively charged region.  Electron will then flow.

The flow of electrons, or electrical discharge will ionize the air around it, and electrons around it get exited, releasing photons, allowing it to be visible to man, when the electrons de-excite.

Comment: Wait doesn't electron flow lower one to a higher one. For ecample as we go further from the electron relative to its field potential also become positive and the a point negative chage will be repelled move to a positive charge. Also for current outside the source it flows from positive to negative and considering the opposite flow of chage shouldn't the electrons travel from lower to higher potential?

Comment: yes thats the case, sorry for the error

Comment: Lol. So holes are the reason for such a phenomenon? Right? So why don't electrical wires get fried? Like the ones used for trains etc.

Comment: No.  Holes are there when electrons leave them.  But that is only for semiconductors.  Usually we've got protons and other positively charged particles. around us causing potential difference.  In the case of the lightning, large amounts or electrons accumulate in the clouds/air, and the PD with the neutral earth causes the lightning @Alexallee

Comment: So the visuals are caused due to the holes only?

Comment: No.  Visuals are caused by photons getting ionized in the air.  the holes part is only for semiconductors only

Comment: What would we see if we were to get a lot of electrons in vaccum containes and apply high PD whould be see any blue lighting or there would only be flow of electrons?

Comment: check out corona discharge.  go google it.  its really cool

Comment: Cool! Thanks i seemed to have put a lot of questions in one thanks for your time. 

Comment: "...and photons around it get exited, releasing light". That is not correct, photons do not get excited releasing light. Electrons in atoms get excited and emit photons when they de-excite, the collection of emitted photons are what we observe and call light.

Comment: @HugoV oops, that should be it

Answer (score 1):

Imagine we have a conductive wire. This wire is composed of positive atomic nuclei (whose positions are fixed relative to eachother) and of electrons that are free to move around the nuclei. I am going to try to avoid using sophisticated jargon, and to stick to simple concepts.

> i found out that moving charges can create electricity why is this possible

As you state, when there is flow of electrons through the wire then there is electricity - the name we give to this flow is "electric current." You ask "why" do moving charges create electricity? WEll, this is a matter of definition: we define a concept called "electricity" to represent the phenomena that result from the flow of electric charges (conceptually, a flow of charges is the same as a current of charges).

Perhaps you are really asking, "what is the difference between electricity and between current?" This is a subtle point. When we connect a voltage source to the two ends of our conducting wire, it will cause electric charges to flow (current) through the wire - that is, each of the electrons in the wire produces an electric field which allows it to communicate to the other electrons near it. As it turns out, the speed of the electrons moving through the wire is significantly less than the speed of electricity through the wire! (this can be seen experimentally by using a capacitor and showing that a light bulb will light up essentially just as fast with or without the capacitor). This means that what we call "electricity" is really the communication process between the electric charges which allows current to flow through the entire wire.

So, moving charges "creates electricity" because the charges have electric fields which allows them to electrically communicate with each other, and when they are under an applied voltage they tell each other to move to the point of low voltage (electric potential).

As Dale pointed out, this concept can be extended to more general distributions of charges so that we have a charge density, $\rho$, and a corresponding current density, $\vec{J}$, which are related by one of Maxwell's equations called Gauss' Law, $\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon}$.