# Why does the flow of charge even create electricity?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-current, charge, flow

Okay this is a question I’ve asked a lot of places but I always get its the flow of charges and it’s like a property. What I don’t really understand is how is this flow of charges creating electric current.

My guess is that as these charges get closer to the desired potential(to satisfy potential difference) Energy is released which happens continuously and it is the reason for electric current atleast in a conductor.

Can I get some insight into what is happening down at the quantum level.

Comment: To my mind a flow of electric charges *is* an electric current.  How do you see them as different?

Comment: Your 2nd paragraph must have many typos because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have this feeling that charges release energy as they satisfy potential difference and this energy is what we call electric current.

Comment: Hey @Bill N does this sound better?

Comment: That doesn't agree with the physics definition of electric current.  Current is the rate of flow of charge across a cross-sectional area.  the definition has nothing to do with energy release.

Comment: oh okay. That’s well fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a moving charge create electricity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/449075/why-does-a-moving-charge-create-electricity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you have to understand that flow of electrical current and dissipation of energy are two completely different concepts.

**Electrical current:** The flow of electrical charges is called electrical current. This is like a definition and has nothing to do with dissipation. There are systems, where current flows without dissipation. At the elementary level, you get the electrical current $I$, if you count, how many elementary charges $e$ cross a specific cross-sectional area of your "conductor" per second. Mathematically this means:
$$ I := \frac{e\Delta N}{\Delta t},$$
where $I$ is the current, $\Delta t$ is the time interval (e.g. 1 second), $e$ is the elementary charge, and $\Delta N$ is the number of elementary charges that you count within time $\Delta t$.
Usually, conductors are metals, and you may think of the cross sectional area of a copper wire, for example. But you can also imagine other "conductors" that are liquids with ions in them, or even gases with charged atoms in them.

**Electrical resistance:** Flowing charge carriers dissipate energy, if they scatter with other particles and thereby lose energy. In metals, for example, electrons forming the electrical current will scatter from lattice vibrations (phonons) and thereby dissipate energy. This energy dissipation leads to electrical *resistance*, usually denoted by $R$.

**Electrical voltage:** Yet another question is, why charge carriers would start to flow at all. In metals, the reason is the applied electrical voltage $U$ between the two ends of a wire. An electrical potential represents the potential energy of charge carriers in an electric field. The voltage is just the difference of the electrical potential at two points (i.e., the difference of the potential energy for the charge carriers between two points). The charge carriers start to flow, because they try to reduce their potential energy (same for the apple falling from a tree: it tries to reduce its potential energy).

**Ohm's law:** The three concepts explained above now are related in Ohm's law, which you may know:
$$ U = R I,$$
which holds for so-called *Ohmic conductors*.

Answer (score 0):

As Bill N said, electric current, $i(t)$ through a surface is defined as the rate of charge transport through that surface, or

$$i(t)=\frac{dq(t)}{dt}$$

Where $q(t)$ denotes instantaneous charge.

Electrical charge gains electrical potential energy from a voltage source (e.g., a battery). This is roughly analogous to a mass gaining gravitational potential energy when it is elevated by something in a gravitational field. Then, if the source is connected to a closed circuit, the electrical charge subjected to forces from the electric field causes it to accelerate gaining kinetic energy and losing potential energy. This is roughly analogous to a falling mass accelerating in a gravitational field, losing its potential energy and gaining kinetic energy.

The difference between the charge and mass analogies is the charge is constantly colliding with atoms (electrical resistance) in the conductor material as it moves through the circuit (an exception would be a superconductor, one with zero resistance).  This causes the charge to alternatively lose some kinetic energy during a collision and regain some kinetic energy from the electric field between collisions. The loss in kinetic energy due to collisions (electrical resistance) generates heat. But charge can also transfer kinetic energy and perform useful work, such as when current operates an electrical mechanical device such as a motor, solenoid, or relay.

In summary, as the charge moves around the circuit, the sum of the losses in potential energy (voltage drops) equals the gain in potential energy from the voltage source (voltage rise), according to Kirchhoff’s voltage law. Along the way the potential energy is converted to kinetic energy, which, in turn, is transferred in the form of heat and/or mechanical work to materials and electrical-mechanical devices.

Hope this helps.